# Heroku PostgressSQL how enable CDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Heroku PostgreSQL and I'm trying to enable CDC (Change Data Capture) so I can use AWS DMS CDC. How do I enable CDC in Heroku PostgreSQL?

Comment: As far as I know, Postgres doesn't have anything called "CDC". Are you looking to [enable logical replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Prerequisites.CDC)?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to enable logical replication. But the issue is that with Heroku I can't do it because I have to be an admin to make these changes and Heroku is blocking me for that. Is there another way?